# How to download image using jQuery AJAX in Laravel 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to download images using jQuery/AJAX in Laravel 8. I get the image in the response, but it is not downloading. Please help me to download the image.

**Controller**

```
public function senddata(Request $req)
{
    $stamp = new Stamp();
    $stamp->company_name = $req->company_name;
    $stamp->reg_no = $req->reg_no;
    $stamp->color = $req->color;
    $stamp->fullname = $req->fullname;
    $stamp->email = $req->email;
    $stamp->save();
    // return Storage::download(public_path('images/Screenshot_1.png'));
    $filepath = public_path('images/')."Screenshot_1.png";
        return Response::download($filepath);
}
```

**jQuery/AJAX Code**

```
$('#acceptform').submit(function () {
    if ($('#acceptform').valid()) {
        var company_name = $('#company_name').val();
        var reg_no = $('#reg_number').val();
        var color = $('input[name="stamp_color"]:checked').val();
        var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ route('senddata') }}",
            data: {company_name: company_name, reg_no: reg_no, 
                color: color, fullname: fullname, email: email},
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            success: function (res) {
                const data = res;
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.setAttribute('href', data);
                link.setAttribute('download', 'Screenshot_1.png');
                link.click();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: you can probably just open that image link in a new window

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use Ajax to download a file, why no simple get request with file id?

Comment: I am trying to first store user data using ajax and after download image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs an answer (even if you do not need ajax to download a file), if you succeeded to get the requested file as a response you can simply download your blob with JavaScript.

Example:

```
function downloadTC(path) {
    let fd = new FormData;
    fd.append('fileName', path);    
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url: '{{ route("download") }}',
        type:"POST",
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        // defining the response as a binary file
        xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' },  
        success: function(response) {
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = path;
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        },
        error: function(blob) {
            console.log(blob);
        }
    }); 
}
```